# put a logo on the top of the drop-down menu - Swift

Tags: swift

Have a nice day. I created a menu with Tableview, I want to add a logo and label to the top of this menu, just like in the android image. How can I make the menu visual like on Android? In the tableview I created, I show the name and icon of the menu. As with Android, I want to add a logo to the top of the menu.

[image: Updated version]

[image: iOS Menu]
[image: android Menu]

```
class MyMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let keychain = KeychainSwift()

    private let menuOptionCellId = "Cell"
    var selectedMenuItemLogin : Int = 0
    var selectedMenuItem : Int = 0
    let menuItem : [String] = ["Giriş"]
       let menuIteminLogin : [String] = ["MENUITEM1" , "MENUITEM2" , "MENUITEM3","MENUITEM4"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64.0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(hex: 0x464646)
        tableView.scrollsToTop = false

        clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        let loginKeychain = keychain.get("LoginSuccess")

        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: selectedMenuItem, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .middle)        
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return menuIteminLogin.count
      }

     var imageinLoginCell : [String] = ["gift.png" , "clock.png", "graphic.png","graphic.png"]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: menuOptionCellId)

                  if loginKeychain == "2" {
                    cell!.textLabel?.text = menuIteminLogin[indexPath.row]
                    cell!.imageView!.image  = UIImage(named: imageinLoginCell[indexPath.row])
                    cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 18)
                    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
                    if let myImage = UIImage(named: imageinLoginCell[indexPath.row]) {
                        let tintableImage = myImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                        cell!.imageView!.image = tintableImage
                    }
                    cell!.imageView!.tintColor = UIColor.white

                    if (indexPath.row == 2){
                        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xcf0700)
                        cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 19)
                    }
        }

        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let loginKeychain = keychain.get("LoginSuccess")
        if loginKeychain == nil {
                   if (indexPath.row == selectedMenuItem) {
                         return
                     }

                     selectedMenuItem = indexPath.row

                     let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
                     var destViewController : UIViewController

                     switch (indexPath.row) {
                              case 0:
                                  destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewNew")
                                  break

                              default:  destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewNew")
                                              break

                     }
                     sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
             ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Add logo image in tableview's header view.

Comment: I updated the subject, but the image of the headerView was confused with the cell item. Do I need to do CGRECT to Cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?"
and this function here for Height "tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat"
It will stick on top and the list will scroll underneath of it.

Comment: I updated the subject, but the image of the headerView was confused with the cell item. Do I need to do CGRECT to Cell?

Comment: Use constraint in the view for imageView and UILabel and you have to return the required height in this func heightForHeaderInSection.
If your logo image size is very big then add the fix height and width constraint to imageView.